# Как удалять дубли при записи списка в csv?

Tags: python, csv

Вот код:

```
def wrinter_csv(product: list[Produs]):
    with open(f'eprr.csv', mode='r+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as fie:
        f = csv.DictReader(fie)
        print(f)
        writer = csv.writer(fie)
        for p in product:
            if p in p:
                print('пропускаю')
                continue
            writer.writerow([p.name,
                     p.price])
```

Comment: используйте библиотеку pandas. ей же читайте свой csv, удаляйте дубли с помощью dropduplicates, и ей же записывайте готовый csv.